# SQL: Find all records in Table A that do not have a value in Table B based on a column value in Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, left-join

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I'm trying to get all businesses who did not make a payment in 2016.

Here is my schema

```
Business Table
---------------
Id     Name
1      Business A
2      Business B

Payments Table
---------------
Id     BusinessId   Year
1      2            2016
2      1            2017
3      2            2017
```

I need a SQL statement that returns Business A since it does not have a payment for 2016.

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT [Business].Name
FROM Businesses as [Business]            
Left Outer JOIN Payments as [Payment]
     ON [Payment].BusinessId = [Business].Id
Where [Business].Id is null and [Payment].TaxYear = 2016
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, the title might be a little convoluted, so a suggested edit for the title of this question would be welcome as well.

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: HINT ... use NOT EXISTS

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I will update the question.

Comment: not B but A since A does not have 2016 payments

Comment: Updated... And I'm giving the NOT Exists a shot now. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT EXISTS, should return Business A since it does not have a 2016 transaction

```
SELECT B.Name
FROM Business as B            
WHERE NOT EXISTS (    
  SELECT 1 FROM Payments P
Where P.TaxYear = 2016
     AND P.BusinessId = B.Id )
```

Comment: I had this previously, minus the "ON P.BusinessId = B.Id". I've added the ON statement, but now get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'". I may have fat fingered something here. I'm using SQL Server 2016, but this code will be hosed on SQL Server 2012 (not sure if that makes a difference)

Comment: sorry.. just typo.. should be okay now

Comment: That works great. When I tried this before, I had left out the AND P.BusinessId = B.Id

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the combination of businesses and years that are not in the payments table.  If so:

```
select b.*
from businesses b cross join
     (select distinct year from payments) y left join
     payments p
     on b.id = p.businessid and b.year = y.year
where p.businessid is null;
```

The `cross join` generates all combinations of businesses and years.  The `left join` and `where` clause then finds the ones that don't exist.

If you are only looking for one year, then @maSTAShuFu answer is the correct approach.

Comment: That works great, but I had to change y.year to the year value. i.e. on on b.id = p.businessid and b.year = 2016

Comment: if you are after of one particular year then this is not the best solution. this solution uses cross join which will create a cartesian product... but if you want to know multiple years skipped then this is your best solution

Comment: @DarrellLloydHarvey . . . You an list the years that you care about in the `y` subquery . . . `(values (2016)) as y(year)`.  That way you can check multiple years at the same time.  But for a single year, @MaSTAShuFu's answer is simpler.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is very useful. I'm going to have to learn more about cross join.